# Moved magento, getting "not supported" message when viewing in browser

Tags: php, apache, magento2

Hi I recently moved a Magento installation from one server to another. These were the steps I took.

1) moved entire file directory.
2) imported database
3) verified composer is working
4) flushed cache, reindexed, verified permissions, verified needed folders are writable.
5) I've verified that I'm running PHP 7.0

I have the index.php set to show errors but I'm not getting any errors at just a white page with the words "Not supported" any ideas?

Comment: Check .htaccess and server log

Comment: The htaccess file is the same file it was on the original server so nothing has changed there. I’m also not getting any errors in the Apache log. When you view the page it just says not supported on a white page